# Как сделать wrapper на весь экран?

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8w9w07H1SsdTUc4d3kzbTZnS2s/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8w9w07H1SsdTy1wZkllRG55Sm8/edit?usp=sharing

Подскажите, как сделать wrapper на весь экран. Только не в px а в %.

Пробовал height на 100% - ничего.

Нужно, чтобы шапка и футер прижимались к краям браузера и центральные блоки тянусь за ними в зависимости от размера экрана. Только одна оговорка, только css.

Comment: Задавать `html,body { min-height:100% }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, высоту все равно нельзя увеличить на 100%, по крайней мере мне - не удавалось. А вот что касается прилипающего футера - не проблема.
Для начала тег футера надо вытащить за пределы враппера т.е.

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper"></wrapper>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

> HTML, BODY, .wrapper { height: 100%; }
>   /* Относится */
>
> BODY .wrapper {   height: auto;
>     min-height: 100%;  }
>
> .wrapper {            margin: 0 auto;
>     width: 940px;   padding: 0 0 113px; /*
>   Относится*/   height: 600px;          }
>
> .footer { margin: -113px auto 0; } /*
>   Относится */

Там, где стоит "относится", это важно, кстати, вы можете высоту враппер-блоку указать как min-height: 200px; т.е. высота по любому быть должна.

P.S. Мне только непонятна формулировка:
Нужно что бы шапка и футер прижимались к краям браузер и **центральные блоки тянусь за ними** в зависимости от размера экрана.
ЭТО КАК? Если вам нужна резиновая верстка, то делите ширину нужного блока на ширину враппера. Например, вам нужно, чтобы левый блок был 200px по дизайну, то в процентах будет 200/100=20% и т.д., и все. Если я не правильно вас понял, то объясните.